# How to properly scale width of SVG parent element in flexbox?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm currently trying to create a navbar for my website. The navbar is implemented using a `ul` container which is set to `display: flex`. Most of the items inside this `flexbox` are `li` tags containing anchor elements, but the first `li` contains an `svg` (a logo).

I'm trying to get the `svg` to responsively scale to the same height as the anchor elements by utilizing the implicit `align-items: stretch` of the `ul`. I would like the width to be automatically calculated using the original aspect ratio of the `svg` and the height.

I was able to get the `svg` to scale to the correct height by adding `height: 100%` to itself and its parent `<a>` tag. This has had the unintended side effect of making the parent `li` have a width of `0`. This causes the `flexbox` to space the elements incorrectly. I've tried in Chrome and Firefox and had the same result regardless, so it seems likely this is intended functionality. I've attached a code snippet below showing the behavior.

Can someone help explain to me how I can fix this without requiring hard-coded values and still fulfilling the requirements above?

```css
nav>ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
    list-style: none;
    gap: 1em;
}

nav>ul>li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

nav>ul>li>a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0;
}

nav>ul>li>a:not(.logo-container>a) {
    color: white;
    background-color: gray;
    padding: 2em;
}

.logo-container>a {
    height: 100%;
}

.nav-logo {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="logo-container">
          <a href="index.html">
            <svg class="nav-logo" id="a" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 164.81 281"><defs><style>.b{fill:#4098ff;}.c{fill:#1463b2;}.d{fill:#0b2c54;}</style></defs><path class="d" d="M1.96,47.61v92.87l53.63,30.95v61.93l-26.8-15.49v-30.92L1.99,171.46v61.93l80.44,46.44V94.05L1.96,47.61Zm53.63,92.9l-26.8-15.49v-30.98l26.8,15.49v30.98Z"/><polygon class="b" points="28.79 186.95 55.59 171.46 28.79 155.97 1.96 171.46 28.79 186.95"/><polygon class="c" points="28.79 217.9 55.59 202.41 55.59 171.46 28.79 186.95 28.79 217.9"/><polygon class="b" points="55.59 233.39 55.59 202.41 28.79 217.9 55.59 233.39"/><polygon class="c" points="28.79 125.03 55.59 109.54 28.79 94.05 28.79 125.03"/><polygon class="b" points="55.59 140.51 55.59 109.54 28.79 125.03 55.59 140.51"/><path class="c" d="M82.42,94.05v185.78l26.8-15.49v-92.87l53.63-30.95V47.61l-80.44,46.44Zm53.6,30.98l-26.8,15.49v-30.95l26.8-15.49v30.95Z"/><polygon class="b" points="109.22 140.51 136.03 125.03 109.22 109.54 109.22 140.51"/><polygon class="d" points="136.03 94.05 136.03 125.03 109.22 109.54 136.03 94.05"/><polygon class="b" points="1.96 47.61 82.42 94.05 162.86 47.61 82.42 1.17 1.96 47.61"/></svg>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

1st solution.
Here SVG image content must be slightly changed - f.e. '#' must be changed on '%23'

```css
nav>ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
    list-style: none;
    gap: 1em;
}

nav>ul>li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

nav>ul>li>a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0;
}

nav>ul>li>a:not(.logo-container>a) {
    color: white;
    background-color: gray;
  opacity: 0.5;
    padding: 2em;
}

.logo-container {
  padding: 2em 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: 
        url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 164.81 281'><path fill='%230b2c54' d='M1.96,47.61v92.87l53.63,30.95v61.93l-26.8-15.49v-30.92L1.99,171.46v61.93l80.44,46.44V94.05L1.96,47.61Zm53.63,92.9l-26.8-15.49v-30.98l26.8,15.49v30.98Z'/><polygon fill='%234098ff' points='28.79 186.95 55.59 171.46 28.79 155.97 1.96 171.46 28.79 186.95'/><polygon fill='%231463b2' points='28.79 217.9 55.59 202.41 55.59 171.46 28.79 186.95 28.79 217.9'/><polygon fill='%234098ff' points='55.59 233.39 55.59 202.41 28.79 217.9 55.59 233.39'/><polygon fill='%231463b2' points='28.79 125.03 55.59 109.54 28.79 94.05 28.79 125.03'/><polygon fill='%234098ff' points='55.59 140.51 55.59 109.54 28.79 125.03 55.59 140.51'/><path fill='%231463b2' d='M82.42,94.05v185.78l26.8-15.49v-92.87l53.63-30.95V47.61l-80.44,46.44Zm53.6,30.98l-26.8,15.49v-30.95l26.8-15.49v30.95Z'/><polygon fill='%234098ff' points='109.22 140.51 136.03 125.03 109.22 109.54 109.22 140.51'/><polygon fill='%230b2c54' points='136.03 94.05 136.03 125.03 109.22 109.54 136.03 94.05'/><polygon fill='%234098ff' points='1.96 47.61 82.42 94.05 162.86 47.61 82.42 1.17 1.96 47.61'/></svg>");    
}

i {
  padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li id="logo" class="logo-container">
          <a href="index.html">
            <i></i>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

2nd solution. Here no need to change SVG content as on my 1st solution. Just copy and paste into JS var.

```js
var mySVG = '<svg class="nav-logo" id="a" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 164.81 281"><defs><style>.b{fill:#4098ff;}.c{fill:#1463b2;}.d{fill:#0b2c54;}</style></defs><path class="d" d="M1.96,47.61v92.87l53.63,30.95v61.93l-26.8-15.49v-30.92L1.99,171.46v61.93l80.44,46.44V94.05L1.96,47.61Zm53.63,92.9l-26.8-15.49v-30.98l26.8,15.49v30.98Z"/><polygon class="b" points="28.79 186.95 55.59 171.46 28.79 155.97 1.96 171.46 28.79 186.95"/><polygon class="c" points="28.79 217.9 55.59 202.41 55.59 171.46 28.79 186.95 28.79 217.9"/><polygon class="b" points="55.59 233.39 55.59 202.41 28.79 217.9 55.59 233.39"/><polygon class="c" points="28.79 125.03 55.59 109.54 28.79 94.05 28.79 125.03"/><polygon class="b" points="55.59 140.51 55.59 109.54 28.79 125.03 55.59 140.51"/><path class="c" d="M82.42,94.05v185.78l26.8-15.49v-92.87l53.63-30.95V47.61l-80.44,46.44Zm53.6,30.98l-26.8,15.49v-30.95l26.8-15.49v30.95Z"/><polygon class="b" points="109.22 140.51 136.03 125.03 109.22 109.54 109.22 140.51"/><polygon class="d" points="136.03 94.05 136.03 125.03 109.22 109.54 136.03 94.05"/><polygon class="b" points="1.96 47.61 82.42 94.05 162.86 47.61 82.42 1.17 1.96 47.61"/></svg>';
var mySVG64 = window.btoa(mySVG);
document.getElementById('logo').style.backgroundImage = "url('data:image/svg+xml;base64," + mySVG64 + "')";
```

```css
nav>ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
    list-style: none;
    gap: 1em;
}

nav>ul>li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

nav>ul>li>a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0;
}

nav>ul>li>a:not(.logo-container>a) {
    color: white;
    background-color: gray;
  opacity: 0.5;
    padding: 2em;
}

.logo-container {
  padding: 2em 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

i {
  padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li id="logo" class="logo-container">
          <a href="index.html">
            <i></i>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```